# Vlookup formula in Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a google sheet which I want my colleague to fill the data manually to cross-check whether there is any difference in the system and the manual notes.

I have the data from the system in the second sheet of the same google sheet. I want the rest of the columns to auto-populate when my colleague enters a value(a column in both sheets - SKU) in a particular column.

Attached the image of the system data which I think of comparing(Lookup), SO my idea is to fill the category name & category ID when my colleague type the SKU in the sheet.

Can anyone help me with this or suggest me what to do? What all I have to do for this?

**This is the sheet which I want my colleague to be filled, SO my requirement is that when my colleague fills the Data in the column "SKU" the other columns should be auto-populated from the sheet3 which has identical SKU.**
[image]

**This sheet contains the values from the system which I have copied.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set up the table of all your SKU's then write the formula as you described. I'm not quite sure where your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in range **Sheet1!B2:D**

paste in **Sheet1!B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet3!A:D, {2,3,4}, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: actually I want the sheet1 to be populated from sheet values.So this should be pasted in sheet1 right?

Comment: Also in sheet1 I have just added a few entries for showing and as an example.where do I paste this and do I need to delete in sheet3?

Comment: I tried teh solution but it's not working.Attached the screen shot for reference.There are two null/0 value in SKU column.But even after I type the same SKU as in sheet3 and pasting the formula you have mentioned above nothing is happening.Any suggestions on this planet

Comment: any suggestions on this?

Comment: How to share it?

Comment: please find the below link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ziEXQ9UN5GFf-X4EbzTpdYXqCJVWhYEA6l2dXTBrBjI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet3!A:D, {2,3,4}, 0)), ))`